# how to delete a pointer to an element in an array java

Tags: java, stack

I am new at java and I am trying to write an array Stack
now I want to avoid loitering in pop () function,

```
public class Stack {
private int[] s;
private int N=0;

public Stack(int capacity)
{
    s= new int [capacity];
}

public boolean IsEmpty ()
{
    return N==0;
}

public void push (int x)
{
    s[N++]=x;
}

public int pop ()
{
    int x=s[--N];
    s[N]=null;
    return x;
}
```

when it decrements that value in, there is still pointer 
to the element that has been took off the stack now I tried to set the removed item to null
but the compiler gives me exception

what can I do in order to delete the pointer of the removed item?!

Comment: Which pointer? You are working with primitives here (`int`), not with objects

Comment: You should just keep a index of your array representing the top of the stack. Which I think is what you are trying to do with `N`.

Comment: You can't set a primitive, such as `int`, to `null`. Only descendants of `Object` can be `null`. It should suffice to only decrement your counter (`N`) in `pop()`, and be sure to correctly set the last stack element in `push()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your array stores `int` values which are not references, and `null` is not a valid value for type `int`.  The trick your are using is handy when you deal with values of reference types, such as `Object` or `String`.  In your case you can assign `0` or `-1` or `Integer.MIN_VALUE` to the empty elements, but not `null`.  Moreover, I think in your case you could just leave value as is:

```
public int pop ()
{
    return s [--N];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an `ArrayList` instead of an array. There you can remove objects at specified position, which will be always the last, in case of a stack.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays of primitives store *values*, not pointers, so you there is no memory leak you have to worry about.

This line:

```
s[N]=null;
```

is not required in java (and does not compile anyway because `null` is not a valid primitive value).

Java ain't C.